# reading large number of files in python

Tags: python, memory-management, io, filesystems

Considering I have a large number of `json` files, but small in size (about 20000 files around 100 Mbs), reading them the first time with code snippet:

```
from time import perf_counter
from glob import glob

def load_all_jsons_serial():
    t_i = perf_counter()
    json_files = glob("*json")
    for file in json_files:
        with open(file,"r") as f:
            f.read()
    t_f = perf_counter()
    return t_f-t_i
load_all_jsons_serial()
```

take around 50 seconds.

However, if I rerun the code, it takes less than a second to finish! Could someone please:

- Explain this observation. Why does it take longer the first time and less for the nexts runs?
- How can I reduce the time for loading for the first time?

I am on a windows 11 machine and run the code in a notebook extension of VSCode.
Thanks.

Comment: @luk2302 the total size of all files is 100MB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read in parallel with  `aiofiles`. Here is a full example, where i had 1000 json files (200kb each) in folder `jsonfiles\async\` and  `jsonfiles\sync\` to prevent any hard disk or OS level caching. Removing the files and recreated the JSON files again after each run.

```
from glob import glob
import aiofiles
import asyncio
from time import perf_counter

###
# Synchronous file operation:
###
def load_all_jsons_serial():
    json_files = glob("jsonfiles\\sync\\*.json")
    for file in json_files:
        with open(file,"r") as f:
            f.read()
    return

t_i = perf_counter()
load_all_jsons_serial()
t_f = perf_counter()
print(f"Synchronous: {t_f - t_i}")


###
# Async file operation
###
async def load_async(files: list[str]):
    for file in files:
        async with aiofiles.open(file, "r") as f:
            await f.read()
    return
        
async def main():
    json_files = glob("jsonfiles\\async\\*.json")
    no_of_tasks = 10
    files_per_task = len(json_files)//no_of_tasks + 1
    
    tasks = []
    for i in range(no_of_tasks):
        tasks.append(
            asyncio.create_task(load_async(
                json_files[i*files_per_task : i*files_per_task+files_per_task]))
        )
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
    return

t_i = perf_counter()
asyncio.run(main())
t_f = perf_counter()
print(f"Asynchronous: {t_f - t_i}")
```

It's not exactly science but you can see there is a significant gain in performance:

```
Synchronous: 13.353551400010474
Asynchronous: 3.1800755000440404
```